# Position all elements after a delimeter an equal distance

Tags: html, css, text, alignment, css-position

I am in the midst of learning CSS and positioning techniques.

I tried googling, but it's sort of a specific case and didn't know how to ask short of typing out the result that I want.

Here is my HTML

```
<h2> "{{title}}" </h2>
<h4><b> Path: </b> "{{path_name}}" </h4>
<h4><b> Last Updated: </b> "{{last_updated}}" </h4> 
<h4><b> Parent: </b> "{{parent}}" </h4>
```

In case anyone is wondering, the {{}} is because those are variables bound to the scope with angular.

Anyway, this is what turns up.

```
HELLO
Path: /abc/def/ghi
Last Updated: Wednesday
Parent: /abc/def
```

Because the names of the fields are differing lengths, the text for each field after the colon is obviously going to be vary where it starts. What I want is something like this.

```
HELLO
Path:              /abc/def/ghi
Last Updated:      Wednesday
Parent:            /abc/def
```

Would anyone know how to align things in such a way? I don't know enough about CSS to properly ask a question via google, without being able to visually represent what I want to do.

Comment: Without changing your markup you could just set you `<b>` elements to `display:inline-block;` and give them a width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use either : `float` or `display:inline-block` and size your `<b>`

Float:

```css
h4  b {float:left;width:6.5em;}
```

```html
<h2> "{{title}}" </h2>
<h4><b> Path </b> "{{path_name}}" </h4>
<h4><b> Last Updated: </b> "{{last_updated}}" </h4> 
<h4><b> Parent: </b> "{{parent}}" </h4>
```

inline-block

```css
h4  b {display:inline-block;width:6.5em;}
```

```html
<h2> "{{title}}" </h2>
<h4><b> Path </b> "{{path_name}}" </h4>
<h4><b> Last Updated: </b> "{{last_updated}}" </h4> 
<h4><b> Parent: </b> "{{parent}}" </h4>
```

Comment: thanks! all of these answers seemed pretty good, so I just went with the one at the top. Learning a bit more CSS every day! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your structure looks a lot like a table to me. Though HTML tables are sometimes overused, I think it would make semantic sense in this case, with the side effect of being a good way to align your elements.

This approach also has the added benefit of not needing to define a fixed width on any of your elements - the table cells will automatically accommodate the size of whatever text is inside them.

Here is an example:

```html
<h2> "{{title}}" </h2>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Path:
    </td>
    <td>
      "{{path_name}}"
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Last Updated:
    </td>
    <td>
      "{{last_updated}}"
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Parent:
    </td>
    <td>
      "{{parent}}"
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Tables are only overused when using them for layout. Never use them for layout, but for displaying data it is 100% acceptable - it's what they are for! This is a good use for tables

Comment: Tables is a VERY bad piece of advice.  It's outdated.

Comment: @durbnpoisn That's not true, for the very reasons listed in this answer and zgood's comment. Please don't spread bad information! Tables are what you should use for tabular data, **always**.

Comment: I suppose that's true.  For what it's worth, I didn't see this as "tabular data" as much as two lists that needed to be next to each other.

Comment: i see no trouble with <table> tag here . a th cell and a td cell side by side is fine and readable, it is better than h2, skipping h3 down to h4 and a b meaningless where a strong or em could have had some meaning. (don't let the troll go to far please :) )

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should be using semantic tags in your html (i.e. `<strong>` instead of `<b>`), but sticking with your provided code, you could do the following:

```
h4 b {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px; // change this to your desired width
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put each list in separate DIVs.  Set the width to the one on the left to be as wide as needed to hold the list.  Set the it to float:left.  The box on the right will appear next to it. 
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/durbnpoisn/tcy2b51r/1/)

```
<style>
#leftBox{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
        min-width:150px;
    border:1px;
}
#rightBox{

}
</style>
HELLO<br />
<div id="leftBox">
Path:<br />
Last Updated:<br />
Parent:
</div>
<div id="rightBox">
/abc/def/ghi<br />
Wednesday<br />
/abc/def
</div>
```